# Incorrect React.js Route path value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I've just added a React.js page to my .Net MVC site.

I think I've got the path value in my  component wrong but I can't figure out what it's supposed to be.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the component to the `Route` prop `Component`. It's called `component` with a lower cased `c`.

```
<Route exact path="/CuteGoatWebsite/Home/React" component={Home} />
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tholle answered my question. I had "Component" with a capital C instead of "component"

Comment: Consider upvoting and accepting my answer instead of answering with my answer yourself.